# StrSplit template

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert this function to a template:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> StrSplit(const std::string& i_str, const std::string& i_delim)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    size_t found = i_str.find(i_delim);
    size_t startIndex = 0;

    while (found != std::string::npos)
    {
        result.emplace_back(std::string(i_str.begin() + startIndex, i_str.begin() + found));
        startIndex = found + i_delim.size();
        found = i_str.find(i_delim, startIndex);
    }
    if (startIndex != i_str.size())
        result.emplace_back(std::string(i_str.begin() + startIndex, i_str.end()));
    return result;
}
```

The goal is to make it support `string` and `wstring`
what I tried:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename T2>
std::vector<T> StrSplit(T& i_str, T2& i_delim)
{
    std::vector<T> result;

    size_t found = i_str.find(i_delim);
    size_t startIndex = 0;

    while (found != T::npos)
    {
        result.emplace_back(T(i_str.begin() + startIndex, i_str.begin() + found));
        startIndex = found + i_delim.size();
        found = i_str.find(i_delim, startIndex);
    }
    if (startIndex != i_str.size())
        result.emplace_back(T(i_str.begin() + startIndex, i_str.end()));
    return result;
}
```

I'm getting this error: `binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

I don't know enough about templates and this error message doesn't help much.

Comment: `T StrSplit(T& i_str, T2& i_delim)` -- Is this right?  You want to return a `T`?  So why does this function instead returns a `std::vector<T>`?

Comment: How are you calling the templated function?

Comment: @Galik `std::vector<std::string> result = StrSplit(text, "|");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem a bit confused about whether `T` is a `std::string` or a `std::vector<std::string>`. Some of your code treats it as the first and some as the second.

Here's my effort. I retained the `const` (why would you remove those) and also have only one template argument, because I can't see that you would want to mix different string types in one function call.

I also removed the explicit `T` constructor call. This isn't necessary when using `emplace_back` in either this code, or in the original code.

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> StrSplit(const T& i_str, const T& i_delim)
{
    std::vector<T> result;

    size_t found = i_str.find(i_delim);
    size_t startIndex = 0;

    while (found != T::npos)
    {
        result.emplace_back(i_str.begin() + startIndex, i_str.begin() + found);
        startIndex = found + i_delim.size();
        found = i_str.find(i_delim, startIndex);
    }
    if (startIndex != i_str.size())
        result.emplace_back(i_str.begin() + startIndex, i_str.end());
    return result;
}
```

Since this code does depend on the parameters being strings a different approach is to template on the character type, not the string type. Like this

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<std::basic_string<T>> StrSplit(const std::basic_string<T>& i_str, const std::basic_string<T>& i_delim)
{
    std::vector<std::basic_string<T>> result;

    size_t found = i_str.find(i_delim);
    size_t startIndex = 0;

    while (found != std::basic_string<T>::npos)
    {
        result.emplace_back(i_str.begin() + startIndex, i_str.begin() + found);
        startIndex = found + i_delim.size();
        found = i_str.find(i_delim, startIndex);
    }
    if (startIndex != i_str.size())
        result.emplace_back(i_str.begin() + startIndex, i_str.end());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: With both templates the compile throws a lot of errors

Comment: @Daniel: How do you call it? Do you (wrongly) mix `std::wstring` with `std::string` delimiter?

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> result = StrSplit(text, "|");`

Comment: @Daniel `"|"` is a `const char[2]` not a `std::string`. Try `std::vector<std::string> result = StrSplit(text, std::string("|"));`

Comment: @Daniel When you use templates the compiler doesn't convert types in the way that you are used to for non-templates. It just takes whatever types you give it and tries to deduce the template parameters from that.

Comment: @Daniel Also if you are using C++14 or later you could use a [std::string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) Like this `std::vector<std::string> result = StrSplit(text, "|"s);`

Comment: Im curently using c++20 when i try `"|"s`  i get an error: `user defined literal operator not found.`

Comment: @Daniel Sorry  to use std::string literals you also need to include `using namespace std::literals;` I forgot about that.

Comment: Thank you john, now it did work. Why when converted to template it doesn't work anymore with just `"abc"` and you need to use the 's' `"abc"s`?

Comment: @Daniel That's just the different rules that apply when calling template functions vs non-template functions. The details are complicated (to say the least) but the basic point is that with a non-template function the compiler knows exactly what types the function requires so it can make more of an effort to convert what is given into what is required. But with template functions the template parameters (which can be any type) means it's not so clear what types are required by the function.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the obvious, as already answered and commented, you may also use a shorter form for splitting the string. C++ has a dedicated functionality for that.

The `std::regex_token_iterator`. Please read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator/regex_token_iterator) about it. It is existing since C++11. Because of the nature of regexes, it is very versatile and powerful. (Though, maybe for some use cases too slow).

With this iterator you can basically iterate over patterns in strings. Or, specify the delimiter as a pattern.

In conjunction with the `std::vector`s [range constructor (5)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), the result is typically a one-liner for splitting a string.

See for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std::string_literals;

template <typename C>
std::vector<std::basic_string<C>> split(const std::basic_string<C>& s, const std::basic_string<C>& delimiter) {
    const std::basic_regex<C> re{ delimiter };
    return { std::regex_token_iterator<std::basic_string<C>::const_iterator, C>( s.begin(), s.end(), re, -1),{} };
}

int main() {
    for (const auto& s : split("aXXbXXcXXd"s, "XX"s)) std::cout << s << ' ';
    for (const auto& ws : split(L"aaXXbbXXccXXdd"s, L"XX"s)) std::wcout << ws << ' ';
}
```